# Supporting different screens, based on the dimension or based on the dpi?

Tags: android

I use API 7. I know there are  two ways for my question:

1- using the `layout-small` and `layout-normal` and `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge`.

2- using the `sw-320dpi` and like this.

When I see the all existing devices (tablet and phones) in the android studio, I understand it does not contain the all existing devices (tablet and phones) in marketplaces. Now I want know your experience about my question. If you want create an application that it uses the API 7, Which method you choose?  I do not want link from other websites, I want  know your experience about supporting different screens? What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use api level 7 so you should use :

layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large and layout-xlarge.
 because using sw-320dp ... begins with android 3.2(api level 13)

Take a look :

Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/. Using the new techniques for declaring layout resources is discussed further in the section about Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not `sw320dpi`, but `sw320dp`. This number doesn't represent screen density, but size in the same manner as `small`/`normal` etc.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> - xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> - large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> - normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> - small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Comment: So, using the `xlarge` folder and `large` folder and `normal`folder and `small` folder is good and enough. right?

Comment: what does 426dp * 320dp mean? Can you pl explain?

Comment: @YuvaRaj dp is a "Density-independent pixel" - that means a point whose physical size is roughly the same for any display density. 10 dp corresponds to about 1.5 mm. The linked article explains this in greater detail.